# Git: tracking only selected entries

Tags: git, version-control

I have a directory, in this directory I have many subdirectories. I want to track only 4 of them (I know they names).

Many people have access to the top directory, and some of them, sometimes are adding new subdirectories.

When I now list the status of the repo with the command

> git status

I get a huge list of 'untracked' entries

How I can tell git, I'm only interested in the four directories I want to track ?

Comment: I guess you have reason not to move those four directories inside a single one, or to make each of them its own repository, or to tell people to stop making new directories there?

Comment: of course, the project layout make it impossible this way ... not my idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gitignore` in the top level directory (or `.git/info/excludes`):

```
*
!/somedir_a/
!/another_dir/
!/dir.the.third/
!/one-last-dir/
```

But if multiple people have access to the top-level directory, they could damage your `.git` dir.

Alternatively, you could just run `git status -uno` (means “do not show untracked files”). Use `git config status.showUntrackedFiles no` to make `git status` work like this by default in that repository.

Comment: That works fine for only showing certain folders, but whenever I try to add something to the commit I have to use the `-f` option. (I am tracking `src/com`, and when I add something without `-f` I get an error like `you're not tracking src, use --force to add anyways`. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't adding the entries you don't want to track in a .gitignore file work?

Best